# Opencart reduce load time while fetching too many data's from database

Tags: loading, opencart, reduce

I'm using attribute filter option in my store. For this i'm using below codes in admin view template. This'll fetch all attributes form database and using jquery tabs i'm hiding all inactive ones.

The weired problem what i'm facing is **LOADING TIME** . I'm having more than 5k products in my store. SO retrieving all attributes taking long time(I think so). Did anyone have any idea to reduce loading time in this case?

```
<div id="tab-subcategory-<?php echo $category['category_id']; ?>" class="htabs-content"> 
       <input name="VALORES_<?php echo $category['category_id']; ?>" type="checkbox" value="1" onclick="Selecbox(this);"/><?php echo $entry_all_values; ?> 
       <input name="VALORES_<?php echo $category['category_id']; ?>" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $category['category_id']; ?>" />
         <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="2" class="list">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                   <td class="left"><?php echo $entry_value; ?><img src="view/image/information.png" width="15" height="15" hspace="10" border="0" align="absmiddle" class="tooltip" title="<?php echo $entry_values_explanation; ?>" /></td>
                   <td class="left"><?php echo $entry_separator; ?> <img src="view/image/information.png" width="15" height="15" hspace="10" border="0" align="absmiddle" class="tooltip" title="<?php echo $entry_separator_explanation; ?>" /></td>
                   <td class="left"><?php echo $entry_examples; ?></td>
                   </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>   

            <?php foreach ($category['attributes'] as $attribute) { ?>

            <tr>
             <td class="left">

             <?php if ($attribute['checked']) { ?>

        <input name="VALORES_<?php echo $category['category_id']; ?>[attributes][<?php echo $attribute['attribute_id']; ?>][attribute_id]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $attribute['attribute_id']; ?>" checked="checked" /><?php echo $attribute['name']; ?>

            <?php }else{ ?>
               <input name="VALORES_<?php echo $category['category_id']; ?>[attributes][<?php echo $attribute['attribute_id']; ?>][attribute_id]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $attribute['attribute_id']; ?>" /><?php echo $attribute['name']; ?>

             <?php } ?>

           </td>

             <td class="left"><input name="VALORES_<?php echo $category['category_id']; ?>[attributes][<?php echo $attribute['attribute_id']; ?>][separator]" type="text" value="<?php echo $attribute['separator']; ?>" size="5"/></td>
             <td class="left"> 
              <?php foreach ($languages as $language) { ?>
              <select  name="select" id="select<?php echo $language; ?>" style="width: 150px" >
            <?php 
       if ($attribute['attribute_values'][$language['language_id']]){ 
                  natsort($attribute['attribute_values'][$language['language_id']]);

                  foreach ($attribute['attribute_values'][$language['language_id']] as $valores_default){ ?>
                     <option><?php echo trim($valores_default); ?></option>
                  <?php } ?>


              <?php }else{ ?>
      <option> <?php echo $text_none; ?></option>
              <?php } ?>


              </select><img src="view/image/flags/<?php echo $language['image']; ?>" title="<?php echo $language['name']; ?>" /><br />
           <?php } ?>


               </td>
            </tr>  
            <?php 

            } ?>
              </tbody>
            </table>

          </div>


          <?php foreach ($category['children'] as $child) { ?>
            <div id="tab-subcategory-<?php echo $category['category_id']; ?>-<?php echo $child['category_id']; ?>" class="htabs-content">


              <input name="VALORES_<?php echo $child['category_id']; ?>" type="checkbox" value="1" onclick="Selecbox(this);"/>
       <?php echo $entry_all_values; ?> 

            <input name="VALORES_<?php echo $child['category_id']; ?>" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $child['category_id']; ?>" />
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="2" class="list">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                      <td class="left"><?php echo $entry_value; ?><img src="view/image/information.png" width="15" height="15" hspace="10" border="0" align="absmiddle" class="tooltip" title="<?php echo $entry_values_explanation; ?>" /></td>
                 <td class="left"><?php echo $entry_separator; ?><img src="view/image/information.png" width="15" height="15" hspace="10" border="0" align="absmiddle" class="tooltip" title="<?php echo $entry_separator_explanation; ?>" /></td>
                   <td class="left"><?php echo $entry_examples; ?></td>

                </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>   

            <?php foreach ($child['attributes'] as $attribute) { ?>
             <tr>
             <td class="left">

             <?php if ($attribute['checked']) { ?>

        <input name="VALORES_<?php echo $child['category_id']; ?>[attributes][<?php echo $attribute['attribute_id']; ?>][attribute_id]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $attribute['attribute_id']; ?>" checked="checked" /><?php echo $attribute['name']; ?>

            <?php }else{ ?>
               <input name="VALORES_<?php echo $child['category_id']; ?>[attributes][<?php echo $attribute['attribute_id']; ?>][attribute_id]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $attribute['attribute_id']; ?>" /><?php echo $attribute['name']; ?>

             <?php } ?>

           </td>

             <td class="left"><input name="VALORES_<?php echo $child['category_id']; ?>[attributes][<?php echo $attribute['attribute_id']; ?>][separator]" type="text" value="<?php echo $attribute['separator']; ?>" size="5"/></td>

             <td class="left">                   
              <?php foreach ($languages as $language) { ?>
              <select  name="select" id="select<?php echo $language; ?>" style="width: 150px" >
           <?php       
       if ($attribute['attribute_values'][$language['language_id']]){ 
                  natsort($attribute['attribute_values'][$language['language_id']]);

                  foreach ($attribute['attribute_values'][$language['language_id']] as $valores_default){ ?>
                     <option><?php echo trim($valores_default); ?></option>
                  <?php } ?>


              <?php }else{ ?>
      <option> <?php echo $text_none; ?></option>
              <?php } ?>


              </select><img src="view/image/flags/<?php echo $language['image']; ?>" title="<?php echo $language['name']; ?>" /><br />
           <?php } ?>

           </td>
            </tr>  
            <?php } ?>
              </tbody>
            </table>
             </div>

             <?php foreach ($child['sisters_id'] as $sister) { ?>
            <div id="tab-subcategory-<?php echo $category['category_id']; ?>-<?php echo $child['category_id']; ?>-<?php echo $sister['category_id']; ?>" class="htabs-content">


              <input name="VALORES_<?php echo $sister['category_id']; ?>" type="checkbox" value="1" onclick="Selecbox(this);"/>
       <?php echo $entry_all_values; ?> 

            <input name="VALORES_<?php echo $sister['category_id']; ?>" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $sister['category_id']; ?>" />
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="2" class="list">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                      <td class="left"><?php echo $entry_value; ?><img src="view/image/information.png" width="15" height="15" hspace="10" border="0" align="absmiddle" class="tooltip" title="<?php echo $entry_values_explanation; ?>" /></td>
                 <td class="left"><?php echo $entry_separator; ?><img src="view/image/information.png" width="15" height="15" hspace="10" border="0" align="absmiddle" class="tooltip" title="<?php echo $entry_separator_explanation; ?>" /></td>
                   <td class="left"><?php echo $entry_examples; ?></td>

                </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>   

            <?php foreach ($sister['attributes'] as $attribute) { ?>
             <tr>
             <td class="left">

             <?php if ($attribute['checked']) { ?>

        <input name="VALORES_<?php echo $sister['category_id']; ?>[attributes][<?php echo $attribute['attribute_id']; ?>][attribute_id]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $attribute['attribute_id']; ?>" checked="checked" /><?php echo $attribute['name']; ?>

            <?php }else{ ?>
               <input name="VALORES_<?php echo $sister['category_id']; ?>[attributes][<?php echo $attribute['attribute_id']; ?>][attribute_id]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $attribute['attribute_id']; ?>" /><?php echo $attribute['name']; ?>

             <?php } ?>

           </td>

             <td class="left"><input name="VALORES_<?php echo $sister['category_id']; ?>[attributes][<?php echo $attribute['attribute_id']; ?>][separator]" type="text" value="<?php echo $attribute['separator']; ?>" size="5"/></td>

             <td class="left">                   
              <?php foreach ($languages as $language) { ?>
              <select  name="select" id="select<?php echo $language; ?>" style="width: 150px" >
           <?php       
       if ($attribute['attribute_values'][$language['language_id']]){ 
                  natsort($attribute['attribute_values'][$language['language_id']]);

                  foreach ($attribute['attribute_values'][$language['language_id']] as $valores_default){ ?>
                     <option><?php echo trim($valores_default); ?></option>
                  <?php } ?>


              <?php }else{ ?>
      <option> <?php echo $text_none; ?></option>
              <?php } ?>


              </select><img src="view/image/flags/<?php echo $language['image']; ?>" title="<?php echo $language['name']; ?>" /><br />
           <?php } ?>

           </td>
            </tr>  
            <?php } ?>
              </tbody>
            </table>
             </div>
      <?php } ?>


      <?php } ?>
```

Comment: I don't think it's weird, I think it's expected with the number of products you have. Did you code this yourself or is it a third party extension?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. its a third party extension

Comment: I recommend contacting this extension developer for assistance, this also will help him to improve his product . I am saying this because I have written some modules before that few customers had issues with because of many products (10k+), I had to rethink and recode a few things.

Comment: Tt's a free one not much support is available from them.

Comment: OK, I see. Can you post a link to that extension, so we could take a look?